# Limit text length to its container size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xdcNe/1/) - We have some div with `header` and `content`. Header may be short - 1 line, or longer 2-3lines high. Content may be very long and need to be `cutted`.

How to cut it to take all the place that is left, but no more. I've been thinking for a while about it and I dont have any 'clean' idea for it.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what your goal is. Are you saying the area needs to have a fixed height, with a scrollbar in it if the text continues past the height of the fixed height?

Answer (score 0):

add this justify attribute in your cont class:

```
text-align:justify;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to cut long text to avoid break line? If I got it, I made a simple example that does what you need. Adjust CSS height according your font-size:

```
<html>
    <style>
        /*header*/
        h2{
            height: 30px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        /*content*/
        div{
            height: 90px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>

    <body>
        <h2>
            Vestibulum vestibulum faucibus metus vel sagittis. Vivamus quis venenatis arcu. Etiam ullamcorper lacinia justo ut tristique. Suspendisse orci tortor, auctor sed posuere nec, porta ac arcu. Nullam varius eleifend felis sed egestas. Mauris aliquam rhoncus risus, ut congue augue sollicitudin eget. Sed ullamcorper placerat eleifend. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce et tincidunt ligula. Integer malesuada ligula sit amet nulla dictum sed tincidunt elit scelerisque. Proin venenatis dolor hendrerit metus consectetur ornare. Nulla sed consectetur libero. Nunc feugiat fermentum enim, eget ornare lorem vehicula ac. Nam volutpat tortor a nisi interdum eu sagittis nibh dapibus. Phasellus aliquam ipsum nec sapien gravida auctor. Donec venenatis, magna ut tempus sollicitudin, nunc turpis lacinia metus, ac suscipit sem sem non nisi.
        </h2>
        <div>
            Vestibulum vestibulum faucibus metus vel sagittis. Vivamus quis venenatis arcu. Etiam ullamcorper lacinia justo ut tristique. Suspendisse orci tortor, auctor sed posuere nec, porta ac arcu. Nullam varius eleifend felis sed egestas. Mauris aliquam rhoncus risus, ut congue augue sollicitudin eget. Sed ullamcorper placerat eleifend. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Fusce et tincidunt ligula. Integer malesuada ligula sit amet nulla dictum sed tincidunt elit scelerisque. Proin venenatis dolor hendrerit metus consectetur ornare. Nulla sed consectetur libero. Nunc feugiat fermentum enim, eget ornare lorem vehicula ac. Nam volutpat tortor a nisi interdum eu sagittis nibh dapibus. Phasellus aliquam ipsum nec sapien gravida auctor. Donec venenatis, magna ut tempus sollicitudin, nunc turpis lacinia metus, ac suscipit sem sem non nisi.
            Vivamus ac felis in sem scelerisque porttitor non non nunc. Cras quis ligula augue, non ornare felis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis eu neque orci. Aenean sit amet lorem tortor. Vivamus et elementum nisi. Sed rhoncus, enim vitae tristique fermentum, purus metus pharetra tellus, non pulvinar orci lectus eget sem. Maecenas vel leo ac nulla aliquam varius id id felis. Maecenas eu vulputate lorem. Sed tincidunt est a turpis gravida pulvinar ac quis augue. Cras pharetra lorem nec arcu lobortis vestibulum. Pellentesque dapibus consequat egestas. Ut aliquam lorem eget risus dictum quis sagittis purus tempus.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```